# Set two strings in logging

Tags: python, logging

so my script goes like this:

```
import logging
LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(message)s - %(asctime)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="newfile.log",
                level=logging.DEBUG,
                format= LOG_FORMAT,
                filemode= 'w')
logger = logging.getLogger()
s1 = "14-03-2019"
s2 = "13    185 Log 357 - sr 6 at realtime"

logger.info(s1+s2)
```

print:

```
INFO 14-03-201913   185 Log 357 - sr 6 at realtime - 2022-01-05 19:14:58,670
```

and what i actually want, is that the s1 will appear first in the line, before the INFO like this:

```
14-03-2019 INFO 13   185 Log 357 - sr 6 at realtime - 2022-01-05 19:14:58,670
```

Comment: what do you want to do with s2? Did you try adjusting the logging format? `LOG_FORMAT`

Comment: @Aditya do you know how can i count the number of lines with specific word?

Comment: yes, you can easily do that, right? If that word exists at the beginning or at the end of the line, then you can use regex's very easily to look for that word of your interest